# Obtaining column of minutes after index start in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
                     Ask Price   Ask Yld
DateTime
2010-03-10 13:00:00   4.031992  0.152202
2010-03-10 13:01:00   4.032859  0.152091
2010-03-10 13:02:00   4.033910  0.151957
2010-03-10 13:03:00   4.034197  0.151920
2010-03-10 13:04:00   4.035106  0.151803
2010-03-11 13:00:00   4.033333  0.166666
```

And has a datetime index spanning many days.

I want to create a column which contains the amount of time in minutes after the first index for that row, that is to create output that looks like this:

```
                     Ask Price   Ask Yld  Minutes after start
DateTime
2010-03-10 13:00:00   4.031992  0.152202  0
2010-03-10 13:01:00   4.032859  0.152091  1
2010-03-10 13:02:00   4.033910  0.151957  2
2010-03-10 13:03:00   4.034197  0.151920  3
2010-03-10 13:05:00   4.035106  0.151803  5
2010-03-11 13:00:00   4.033333  0.166666  1440
```

I know that I can simply do one datetime minus the other to find the timedelta - but I don't know how to apply this to make a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a subtraction to get a TimeDeltaIndex, this has a [`.seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.seconds.html#pandas.TimedeltaIndex.seconds) attribute and you can just divide this by 60 to get minutes:

```
In [220]:
df['Minutes after start'] = (df.index - df.index[0]).seconds/60
df

Out[220]:
                     Ask Price   Ask Yld  Minutes after start
DateTime                                                     
2010-03-10 13:00:00   4.031992  0.152202                    0
2010-03-10 13:01:00   4.032859  0.152091                    1
2010-03-10 13:02:00   4.033910  0.151957                    2
2010-03-10 13:03:00   4.034197  0.151920                    3
2010-03-10 13:04:00   4.035106  0.151803                    4
```

**EDIT**

You can cast the timedeltaindex to `timedelta64[s]`:

```
In [237]:
df['Minutes after start'] = (df.index - df.index[0]).astype('timedelta64[s]')/60
df

Out[237]:
                     Ask Price   Ask Yld  Minutes after start
DateTime                                                     
2010-03-10 13:00:00   4.031992  0.152202                    0
2010-03-10 13:01:00   4.032859  0.152091                    1
2010-03-10 13:02:00   4.033910  0.151957                    2
2010-03-10 13:03:00   4.034197  0.151920                    3
2010-03-10 13:04:00   4.035106  0.151803                    4
```

This should be equivalent to total seconds

Comment: This works but only during the day after the first index value - i.e. once it hits 13:00:00 on the next day the minutes after resets to 0 again. See the question for an edited update.

Comment: Using .total_seconds() instead of .seconds() seems like it could work?

Comment: Though I get the error `AttributeError: 'TimedeltaIndex' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'` when trying to use total_seconds() instead of seconds...

Comment: Yes `total_seconds` was what I was going to update this to, have to convert to py_timedelta

Comment: I look forward to your update as I can't figure out how to use `total_seconds` without it throwing that attribute error.

Comment: I think casting to `timedelta64[s]` should work correctly